# How can I combine two ISP connections wirelessly to create one wireless network between two homes?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

In a Windows 7 environment, can 2 neighbors establish a combined, wirelessly connected, bridged network in order to share both broadband access points AND files across a Homegroup environment or the like using a system of 2 modems, 2 wireless routers, wireless access points and/or repeaters, switches, etc? My neighbor and I want to establish ONE wireless/wired network between our 2 homes.

Comment: I have to ask...where do you live roughly? And, who is your ISP?

Comment: How far is it (roughly)

Comment: Distance and ISP aren't a factor.  If you share broadband access, you therefore can both be on the same network, and therefor can share files.

I hope that they're not to far apart though.

Comment: you'll need this [coaxial cable splitter](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&rlz=1C1GPCK_enUS369US369&qscrl=1&q=coaxial+cable+splitter&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1152&bih=763&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=17439560751288124161&sa=X&ei=NL04Tpf5BIbn0QGj35zWAw&sqi=2&ved=0CH0Q8wIwAA)

Comment: @wizlog I am not asking for a technology reason. Most ISP's in the US forbid this type of sharing unless you have specific types of accounts (like business), and I was going to check. He could be in for a big fine if he did it, and I was just going to point that out, but I was going to do reasearch on his ISP first.

Comment: As long as you don't touch any of their cables. ex off of your modem/router/slitter, you put one Ethernet cable into port 2 of 4, and string that out the window.  That's illegal or prohibited? Source plz.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to double your bandwidth and that's the reason you don't want to just jump together on one connection. Keep in mind, however, that you may be breaking the ToS of your ISP so be careful!

Anyway.  This isn't a typical use case for home consumer products. I'd suggest that you want to do the "merge" as early as possible (i.e. avoid using software to handle it -- do it at the router level).  The sooner on the network chain that you turn it into a single connection the less trouble you'll face.

Corporate routers can support multiple connections (or "uplinks") -- Here is an example of a router that can do this: [http://www.amazon.com/Cisco-RV082-8-port-100-Router/dp/B0000ZI1FG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1312387502&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000ZI1FG)

Using this type of router you can create a network that is powered across two WAN connections and build up from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reasons why you want to do this, but financially and security wise it makes more sense to have only one wireless access point, and use that between the two homes. is distance is an issue, you can use an wireless extender antenna to boost the wireless signal.